# CSS animation flickering in MS Edge

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I've got problem with Facebook Slider Widget on my website and I don't know how to fix this. It works fine in all major browsers exept IE and Edge. It won't open, properly, just flickering.

You can check this [here](https://www.nikolecollection.com/bg/)

Thank you

Comment: Where is this Facebook Slider supposed to be? Nothing is flickering, nothing is broken.

Comment: `exept IE and Edge` have you tried this browsers?

Comment: Yes, I opened your site on Edge as well as Chrome to compare. They were identical.